# Parsing datetime gives an error with word starting at index 3

Tags: c#, date, datetime, console, console-application

I have datetime in string format which is like this:

```
24-ago-19 19:21:14
```

Or format like this:

```
Aug-24-19 19:21:14
```

When  I use this on second format:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateTime);
```

It parses the datetime correctly- however on the first format:

```
24-ago-19 20:21:14
```

I get an error like this:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown
>   word starting at index 3

How can I handle conversion of any date format - and preferably convert it to "Pacific Standard Time" ?

What am I doing wrong here ? Can someone help me out?

Comment: What language is "ago"? You probably need to tell `DateTime.Parse` to use the CultureInfo for that language.

Comment: @canton7 french or spanish, Im not sure

Comment: You need to add a Culture to the Parse. Default is not the right culture.

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* parse both `ago` and `Aug` with the same [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) *without* any string manipulation in your custom string format.

Let's run some code first;

```
foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    if (culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Contains("ago") ||
        culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.Contains("ago"))
    {
       if (culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Contains("Aug") ||
           culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.Contains("Aug"))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(culture.Name);
       }
    }
}
```

This code does not write any `CultureInfo` name in my computer, and probably wouldn't print in yours either. That means, there is no culture information that includes both of these month name and abbreviate month name. Even I check the genitive month names (which includes on [`AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthgenitivenames?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`MonthGenitiveNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthgenitivenames?view=netframework-4.7.2) properties) but no luck.

If you can parse `Aug-24-19 19:21:14` string with `DateTime.Parse` directly, that means your [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8) has `Aug` as an abbreviated month name and `MMM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss` as a standart date and time format.

> How can I handle conversion of any date format

You *can't.* You **have to** know what kind of format your string exactly to prevent ambiguous situations. For example, let's take `01-02-2019` string. Is it January 2nd or February 1st? Can you even tell this by looking only it's format? Different people on different regions around the world read this format differently.

> and preferably convert it to "Pacific Standard Time"

After you parse your string successfully (remember your `DateTime.Kind` should be `Local`), you can use [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netframework-4.8) method to convert it like;

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse("Aug-24-19 19:21:14 "); 
var myPSTdate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(myDate , "Pacific Standard Time");
```

> What am I doing wrong here?

As far as I can see, you are not doing anything wrong. Your inputs are not reliable to parse with the same culture information. That's it. Some people call this situation as [garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). If you *can* fix your inputs, your duty should be to fix their format first.